# Do I have to create a new docker container to run each rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Say I have a `Dockerfile` that will run a Ruby on Rails app:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1

# - apt-get update, install nodejs, yarn, bundler, etc...
# - run yarn install, bundle install, etc...
# - create working directory and copy files
# ....

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

From my understanding, a container is an immutable running instance of an image and a set of runtime options (e.g. port mappings, volume mappings, networks, etc...).

So if I build and start a container from the above file, I'll get something that executes the default `CMD` above (`rails server`)

```
docker build -t myapp_web:latest
docker create --name myapp_web -p 3000:3000 -v $PWD:/app -e RAILS_ENV='production' myapp_web:latest
docker start myapp_web
```

Great, so now it's running `rails server` in a container that has a `CONTAINER_ID`.

But lets say tomorrow I want to run `rake db:migrate` because I updated something. How do I do that?

1. I can't use `docker exec` to run it in that container because `db:migrate` will fail while `rails server` is running
2. If I stop the `rails server` (and therefore the container) I have to create a *new container* with the same runtime options but a different command (`rake db:migrate`), which creates a new `CONTAINER_ID`. And then after runs that I have to restart my original container that runs `rails server`.

Is #2 just something we have to live with? Each new rake task I run that requires `rails server` to be shut down will have to create a new CONTAINER and these pile up over time. Is there a more "proper" way to run this?

Thanks!

*EDIT*: If #2 is the way to go, is there an easy way to create a new container from an existing container so I can copy over all the runtime configs and just change the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is incredibly routine to stop, delete, and recreate containers.  If you fixed a typo in a view template and want to update your system, the generally correct Docker path is to build a new image with the fix, stop and delete the old container, and start a new container based on the new image.

There are two tricks that can help the scenario you describe.  First of all, when you `docker run` a container with a `--name`, you can use that name for all subsequent Docker operations; you never need to know the hex container ID.  Second, when you run a one-off command, you can add a `--rm` option so that the container deletes itself when it finishes.

So this workflow might look like:

```sh
# Build the new image
docker build -t myapp_web:latest .

# Stop and delete the old server
docker stop myapp_web
docker rm myapp_web

# Run the migration task
docker run --rm myapp_web:latest rake db:migrate

# Restart the server
docker run -d --name myapp_web -p 3000:3000 myapp_web
```

You can also look at the [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/) command to clean up unused containers and images.  I second the recommendation of Docker Compose to encapsulate simple `docker run` options, but you can also write sequences of commands like this into a shell script instead of typing them out by hand repeatedly.

Comment: Thank you this helps *a lot*. When you build a new image are you talking about git pull-ing your repo into some host tmp dir and re-copying the entire code into a container to rebuild? A lot of tutorials (e.g: rubyinrails.com/2019/03/29/dockerify-rails-6-application-setup) recommend permanently mounting the cloned directory as a volume on the container (`--volume .:/app`). Your approach de-couples host & container (yay!) but a full rebuild takes longer right? Also, with your approach I assumed it's still correct to cache `node_modules/`and ruby gem installations to avoid re-building those?

Comment: The approach I find works well is to use something like an [rvm gemset](http://rvm.io/gemsets/basics) to provide an isolated environment for doing actual development, and build a Docker image mostly for deployment.  In the case of a Node application, the `node_modules` tree is its own isolation.  Try to separate out installing dependencies from installing your application in your Dockerfile to minimize rebuild time.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using docker-compose. In my codebase I'll name my docker-compose section for rails 'web', and then when I want to run rails console for instance I'll do:

```
docker-compose run web bundle exec rails console
```

And you can use the entry point script to run rails console, that way you would start the server by running:

```
docker-compose up
```

In the apps directory.

More information on docker-compose here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

More reasons to use compose rather then starting docker images manually:
- Provides a syntax for setting things like the exposed ports per image, instead of writing that out everytime
- Makes it easy to launch multiple images at once, ie, I have containers in my compose file for: rails, redis, postgres, sidekiq, etc. Sooner or later you'll want multiple images.
- Easy to specify local or remote images. You can use `up` to both build and start your stack. Easy to get new developers up and running.

Comment: Ah so I forgot to mentiont that I'm aware that docker compose exists, and I'll eventually use that in production. But for my own education I'd like to learn the manual long approach first. Does docker compose secretly build a new container and then remove it like I described? What would I do if I *didn't* have docker compose available? Thanks!

Comment: Can't help you much there because my workflow is way different. I use docker-compose in development and kubernetes in production. And I'd argue this is the best approach nowadays :p